# How to reorder a table with the number of the columns with a specific value

Tags: mysql, sql

I hava a table like this.

```
ID   F01   F02   FO3
1    1     0     0
2    1     1     0
3    1     1     1
```

I Want the table reOrder like this

```
ID   F01   F02   FO3
3    1     1     1
2    1     1     0
1    1     0     0
```

Because the row 3, have 3, one in it's row.
row 2, have two, one in it's row.
and row1 have, the one , one in it's row.

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the order of the records within the table, or are you after a query that orders the records?

Comment: Where would the records (4,1,0,1) and (5,0,1,1) appear in the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean physically reordering, don't do this. There is no "order" in a database table, unless you specify it with `ORDER BY`.

```
SELECT
*
FROM
your_table
ORDER BY F01 + F02 + F03 DESC
```

If you're looking for a specific value that is not 1, you can do it like this:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
your_table
ORDER BY IF(F01 = 'some_value', 1, 0) + IF(F02 = 'some_value', 1, 0) + IF(F03 = 'some_value', 1, 0) DESC
```

Comment: Your second query can be rewritten with `ORDER BY (F01='some_value') + (F02='some_value') + (F03='some_value') DESC`

Comment: The usual way to say "thanks" here is by accepting the answer. Others will also know then, that the issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the results ordered by each column in turn, something like:

```
  SELECT *
    FROM table1
ORDER BY f01 DESC, fo2 DESC, f03 DESC
```

Splitting the columns in the `ORDER BY` allows indexes to be used.

If you are looking for the sum of the values fancyPant's answer is more suited.